# camel: use header value in multiple routes

Tags: apache-camel, messaging

Is it possible to set a header in one route and then use it again later in another route in the same context?
For example, I have a route that sets a header as so:

```
<setHeader headerName="clientId">
   <xpath>/Alarm/clientid/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

The route uses Dead Letter Channel to send the message to an error route in the same context when delivery fails and I would like to use the clientId header I defined above in the message the error route sends, but currently calling the header returns nothing (an empty string I assume).

Comment: As long as you are not doing anything with the exchanges this should work. I use this in my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work , I am using camel 2.15.1 ,check the code below , if you run it you should see the header

```
<bean id="mybean" class="java.lang.Exception" />
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    trace="false">
    <camel:errorHandler id="deadLetterErrorHandler"
        type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="direct:b">

    </camel:errorHandler>

    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
        <camel:setHeader headerName="myheader">
            <camel:simple>Sundar</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:to uri="direct:a" />

    </camel:route>
    <camel:route errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler">
        <camel:from uri="direct:a" />
        <camel:throwException ref="mybean"></camel:throwException>
    </camel:route>

    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="direct:b" />
        <camel:log message="${in.header.myheader}"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

It should print a log like below

```
24 Feb 2016 19:09:47,707  route3 INFO  Sundar
```

Comment: You answer is correct but my case was different (which I didn't properly describe in the question sorry).  In my I was sending the message from the first route to a queue, consuming from that queue in a bean and then sending a message to another route.  The issue was me not setting the header in the java